# Running a local instance of apache without admin rights on Mac OS X

Tags: php, apache, macos, root

I'd like to make a portable version of apache/php to develop locally.

But the problem is about binding a port. That process requires admin rights, which I don't have on my workstation.

I'd like to compile an apache/php version which I'd transfer on my workstation and run it without any rights requirements.

I read about privbind, but in the end, you still need those damn admin rights!

Any idea about maybe some kind of virtual port mapping or whatever-may-work-without-root?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a question more suited to Server Fault or Super User.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to compile it yourself, get it from here: http://bitnami.org/stack/mampstack

It uses higher than 1024 port numbers by default, so it should be fine without admin privileges. Includes Apache, PHP, MySQL and phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 9):

You really need root privileges to bind any port below 1024, 80 is not an exclusion. Consider using a higher port, like 8080 (or something less common).

Answer (score 0):

Or grant sudo access to the user.

Comment: That's not really portable (sudo), and sudo is actually giving root permissions.

Comment: but you can limit limit what the user can run. But I agree, he'll have to modify the port to something other than port 80.

Comment: You can only limit *what* applications can be run. But after that, you're granting full root privileges to that application.

Comment: `sudo` **is** admin essentially

Answer (score 0):

Apache/PHP comes bundled by default on MacOS. My Snow Leopard install has PHP 5.3.2.

Honestly, though, I'm not 100% sure if PHP was updated when I installed XCode or not. More information about the bundled version is on the [PHP Website](http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.bundled.php).

MySQL is not included, however. Some people also prefer to use bundled installers which include separate versions of Apache and PHP, and bundle MySQL. I favor [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/index), but others seem to favor [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/).